# Tabs style in the Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm new in the Cocoa programming and now I'm designing an application with several tabs. Unfortunately I don't like the style of the standard tabs view, however I was lucky to find something with tabs style I'm looking for. Screenshot can be found here:
http://investoscope.com/images/scr1.png
And the question is how to implement (where to start) tabs as in the picture from the link. (I mean tabs at the bottom of the picture (Summary, Holidays, Realized, etc.))

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Krokodylowy

Comment: Those look just like the iTunes tabs...

Answer (score 3):

That's definitely custom.  I'd probably start by subclassing `NSTabViewItem` and overriding `drawRect:` to do the custom drawing of the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the link above and it works fine under 10.6.x

### (In fact is't a reeeealy nice looking control and is a good starting point to get what you want)

[This link](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControlPalette.zip) worked without any code changes:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PSMTabBarControl

http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html

The creator hasn't updated, so to get something compilable on 10.6 you'll need to google around a bit. If you can't find it, let me know and I'll find you a link.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ENTabBarView

https://github.com/aaron-elkins/ENTabBarView

It's open source and written by me.